# Named piped error

Tags: c, pipe, named

Sorry for the poor title, i didnt' know how to explain this simply.
I have 2 programs : a server and a client.
Server make a named pipe and waits to read something. Client connects and send a message to the pipe. Server checks a part of the message to get the "type" of the message (in this case, type is "HELO") reading char 4 to 8 of the sent string. If i send "HELO", server prints "Type : HELO" as expected.
But if i send a message with something else, it doesn't print "No match" as expected : it just does nothing.
Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUF_SIZE 256

char * getType(char * message){
  char* type = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
  memcpy(type,&message[4],4);
  type[4] = '\0';
  return type;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  mkfifo("tchatserv", 0666); 
  int fd = open("tchatserv", O_RDONLY);
  char buf[BUF_SIZE];
  int val;
  while(1){
    val = read(fd, buf , BUF_SIZE );
    if(val >0){
      char * type = getType(buf);
      if(strcmp("HELO",type) == 0){
        printf("Type: %s\n", type);
      }
      else{
        printf("no match");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is client :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

char * makeInt(int val){ 
  char* res = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
  char l [5] = "";
  sprintf(l,"%d",val);
  if(val < 10){
    strcat(res,"000");
    strcat(res,l);
  }
  else if(val < 100){
    strcat(res,"00");
    strcat(res,l);
  }
  else if(val < 1000){
    strcat(res,"0");
    strcat(res,l);
  }
  else if( val < 10000){
    strcat(res,l);
  }
  return res;
}

char * makeString(char * ch, int final){ 
  int t = strlen(ch);   
  if(final == 1){
    t = t+4;
  }
  char * chaine = makeInt(t);
  strcat(chaine,ch);
  return chaine;
}
void connection(){ 

  printf("Pseudo:\n");
  char * pseudo = malloc(sizeof(char)*30);
  pseudo[0] = '\0';
  scanf("%s", pseudo);

  printf("Tube:\n");
  char * tube = malloc(sizeof(char)*30);
  tube[0] = '\0';
  scanf("%s", tube);

  char * message = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
  char * type = "HELO";
  message[0] = '\0';
  strcat(message,type);
  pseudo = makeString(pseudo,0);
  strcat(message,pseudo);
  tube = makeString(tube,0);
  strcat(message,tube);
  message = makeString(message,1);
  printf("%s",message);
  int fd = open("tchatserv", O_WRONLY);
  write(fd,message,256);
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  connection();
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: When i try to send something else than HELO it doesn't print "no match" but then i send HELO and it prints : "no match Type: HELO", like if the first "no match" got stuck in the pipe instead of getting printed immediately, i don't understand why.

Comment: `strcat(message,type);` That is a bug and leads to Undefined Behaviour. `message` contents are not initialised and contains random garbage. `strcat` requires a NUL terminated string. Use `strcpy` or set `message[0]='\0'`

Comment: When i send "HELO" it seems to work. I corrected the problem though but still the same issue.

Comment: Your `makeString` function has a return type of `char*` but doesn't return anything. That's going to cause problems.

Comment: Indeed it should be a void, thank you.

Comment: UB means that the result is unpredictable. Sometimes it may appear to work but under different conditions it will fail. Never imply "code has major bug but still works". Please update your code with what you changed so others don't need to point it out again. And use a debugger.

Comment: But you have not fixed the same bug in other places. `strcat(res,"000");` where `res` contents are garbage.

Comment: `char* res = malloc(sizeof(char)*4);` and that can only fit a string of *three* characters plus the NUL terminator. Yet you are writing in a string of *four* characters.

Comment: Thank you, just edited the whole code. Also added an information about the bug.

Answer (score 0):

> When i try to send something else than HELO it doesn't print "no match" but then i send HELO and it prints : "no match Type: HELO", like if the first "no match" got stuck in the pipe instead of getting printed immediately, i don't understand why.

The `no match` indeed *got stuck* in a way, though not in the pipe, but rather in the server's buffer of the standard output stream, which is presumably *line buffered*, i. e., *characters are transmitted* (printed) *when a new-line is encountered*. To cure this, just change the `printf("no match")` to `printf("no match\n")` or `puts("no match")`.